# Dynamically creating Checkboxes while not knowing the number of them in Android studio

Tags: java, android, checkbox

I am trying to create a user registration activity in Android Studio, where the Manager registers the employees and selects the actions the employee is allowed to do.
I have done the registration in PHP and looks like this:

```
    <?php foreach ($action_item as $key => $value):?>

    <input type="checkbox" name="actions[]" value="<?php echo $value['ID_action'] ?>"><?php echo $value['Action_Name'] ?><br>

       <?php endforeach; ?>
```

The actions are stored in the "Actions" table. And the code inserts their IDs in the "Employee_has_action" table with the structure(Id_EHA, ID_employee, ID_action). I know how to insert to and retrieve data from online DB with json, so the question is how to (if possible) dynamically make several (number of retrieved database rows from Action table) checkboxes through code and give them the retrieved values?
Or any other better options where at user register the manager selects multiple data and they get inserted to DB?

Thanx in advance.

Comment: What you want is to show some info with a checkbox for each record in the Action table in a native Android app?

Comment: More like I want to programmatically create several checkboxes on the layout, so if my sql = "SELECT COUNT(ID_Action) .... " returns 5 then create 5 checkboxes with the name of the actions. Values wont be a problem, the problem is the programatic creation of the checkboxes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My first choice would be to present the information in a `RecyclerView` and have an item layout (xml) with the `checkbox` already there.

But if you want to dinamically create the checkboxes, you can:

1) In the `layout` you will be using include a holder for the `checkboxes` (a `parent`) with an `id` you can `findViewById()` from the program to `appendView()` them upon creation.

2) Create the `checkboxex` in a loop (0 to 4 in your 5 actions example) and give them an `id` (See `View.generateViewId()` to get an Id that doesn't collide with other existing ones).
You will also have to create and set the `LayoutParams` for each `checkbox` (different `instance` for each `checkbox`). The `LayoutParams` you will have to set will depend on the layout where you are putting the `checkboxes`.
And finally add the `checkbox` to the `view` with `parent.appendView()`.

As a last step you may need to `ivalidate()` the parent or call `requestLayout()` on the parent view.

More or less this is how it should go.